# Issues Rotating a Model by a Slider in C#/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

Good Evening,

I'm currently trying to rotate "Joint 1" around a given axis using a slider that is scaled from 0-360'. I have bound my slider to get the value, and put it in a function "Move_Joint1" which is supposed to apply a rotation to the object based on the slider input from the user. However, when putting the function in my mainwindow, but the function doesn't seem to execute. I have tried to use console.writeline to try output the value but nothing is outputted. There are no errors or warnings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the XAML and C# code snippets below.

C#

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;
 using System.Windows.Data;
 using System.Windows.Documents;
 using System.Windows.Input;
 using System.Windows.Media;
 using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
 using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
 using System.Windows.Navigation;
 using System.Windows.Shapes;
 using HelixToolkit.Wpf;
 namespace AtlasWPF
 {
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // Model Group - Contains all parts
    Model3DGroup AtlasModel;
    // 3D World
    BoxVisual3D MyBox;
    // Atlas Parts
    Model3D Stand;
    Model3D Shoulder1;
    Model3D Arm1;
    Model3D Arm2;
    Model3D Wrist1;
    Model3D Wrist2;
    Model3D Wrist3;


    public Model3D our_Model { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //The Importer to load .obj files
        ModelImporter importer = new ModelImporter();

        //The Material (Color) that is applyed to the importet objects
        Material material = new DiffuseMaterial(newSolidColorBrush(Colors.Beige));
        importer.DefaultMaterial = material;

        //instanciate a new group of 3D Models
        AtlasModel = new Model3DGroup();

        //load the files
        Stand = importer.Load(@"Models/stand.obj");
        Shoulder1 = importer.Load(@"Models/GUI Joint Shoulder 1.obj");
        Arm1 = importer.Load(@"Models/GUI Full Arm.obj");
        Arm2 = importer.Load(@"Models/GUI Full Arm 2.obj");
        Wrist1 = importer.Load(@"Models/GUI Joint Wrist 1.obj");
        Wrist2 = importer.Load(@"Models/GUI Joint Wrist 2.obj");
        Wrist3= importer.Load(@"Models/GUI Tool Tip.obj");

        //add them to the group
        AtlasModel.Children.Add(Stand);
        AtlasModel.Children.Add(Shoulder1);
        AtlasModel.Children.Add(Arm1);
        AtlasModel.Children.Add(Arm2);
        AtlasModel.Children.Add(Wrist1);
        AtlasModel.Children.Add(Wrist2);
        AtlasModel.Children.Add(Wrist3);

        //AtlasModel is complete assign it to the global variable
        this.our_Model = AtlasModel;

        //instanciate Helper box, uncomment to use it

        MyBox = new BoxVisual3D
        {
            Height = 15,
            Width = 15,
            Length = 15
        };
        m_helix_viewport.Children.Add(MyBox);

        // Set Joints in correct locations and orientations.
        //rotate whole Model to have it upright
        RotateTransform3D myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), 180));
        myRotateTransform.CenterX = 0;
        myRotateTransform.CenterY = 0;
        myRotateTransform.CenterZ = 0;
        AtlasModel.Transform = myRotateTransform;

        // Set Shoulder Position
        Vector3D axis0 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
        Matrix3D transformationMatrix = Shoulder1.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix.Translate(new Vector3D(0, 0, 185));
        Shoulder1.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix);

        // Set Arm1 Position
        Vector3D axis1 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1); //In case you want to rotate it about the x-axis
        Matrix3D transformationMatrix1 = Arm1.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix1.Translate(new Vector3D (0,150,253));
        Arm1.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix1);
        transformationMatrix1 = Arm1.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix1.Rotate(new Quaternion(axis1, 270)); //Makes a rotation transformation over this matrix
        Arm1.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix1);

        //Set Arm2 Position
        Vector3D axis2 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1); //In case you want to rotate it about the x-axis
        Matrix3D transformationMatrix2 = Arm2.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix2.Translate(new Vector3D(0, 0, 825));
        Arm2.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix2);
        transformationMatrix2 = Arm2.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix2.Rotate(new Quaternion(axis2, 0)); //Makes a rotation transformation over this matrix
        Arm2.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix2);

        // Set Wrist Position
        Vector3D axis3 = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0); //In case you want to rotate it about the y-axis
        Matrix3D transformationMatrix3 = Wrist1.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix3.Translate(new Vector3D(1280, 0, 60));
        Wrist1.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix3);
        transformationMatrix3 = Wrist1.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix3.Rotate(new Quaternion(axis3,270)); //Makes a rotation transformation over this matrix
        Wrist1.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix3);
        transformationMatrix3 = Wrist1.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        axis3 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);// To Rotate around Z-axis
        transformationMatrix3.Rotate(new Quaternion(axis3, 180)); //Makes a rotation transformation over this matrix
        Wrist1.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix3); //Apply Transform

        // Set Wrist Position 2
        Vector3D axis4 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1); //In case you want to rotate it about the z-axis
        Matrix3D transformationMatrix4 = Wrist2.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix4.Translate(new Vector3D(0, -115, 1340));
        Wrist2.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix4);
        transformationMatrix4 = Wrist2.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix4.Rotate(new Quaternion(axis4, 90)); //Makes a rotation transformation over this matrix
        Wrist2.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix4);

        // Set Wrist Position 3 /Tool

        Vector3D axis5 = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1); //In case you want to rotate it about the z-axis
        Matrix3D transformationMatrix5 = Wrist3.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix5.Translate(new Vector3D(60, -115, 1395)); // Translates to apply .obj
        Wrist3.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix5); // Translation applied
        transformationMatrix5 = Wrist3.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix5.Rotate(new Quaternion(axis5, 90)); //Makes a rotation transformation over this matrix
        Wrist3.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix5); //Applies New Matrix to previous.

        Move_Joint1(slJoint1.Value);
        #endregion

        Console.WriteLine(slJoint1.Value);
        overall_grid.DataContext = this;
    }
    //Moves Joint 1
    public void Move_Joint1(double angle)
    {
        Output(slJoint1.Value);
        Matrix3D transformationMatrix7 = Shoulder1.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
        transformationMatrix7.Rotate(new Quaternion(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1),angle)); ; //Makes a rotation transformation over this matrix
        Shoulder1.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix7);

    }
    private void Output(double context) => Console.WriteLine(context);
    private void TextBox_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
 }
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="AtlasWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns:HelixToolkit="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AtlasWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1366" WindowState="Maximized">
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save_As" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header=" _Edit">
            <MenuItem Header="_Undo"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Redo"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header=" _View">

        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Help">
            <MenuItem Header="About Atlas"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Documentation"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Visit Atlas"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" FontSize="8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
        <StatusBarItem VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock/>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <GroupBox Header="Position" Height="716">
                <StackPanel Margin="3,0,-3,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Padding="3"> Joint 1</TextBlock>
                    <Slider Maximum="360" Minimum="0" x:Name="slJoint1"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMin1" Padding="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Min</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbVal1" Padding="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Value</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMax1" Padding="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Max</TextBlock>

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint1, Path=Minimum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbMinBox1" Padding="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint1, Path=Value,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbValBox1" Padding="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="50" InputScope="Number" Width="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint1, Path=Maximum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbMaxBox1" Padding="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"></TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Padding="3"> Joint 2</TextBlock>
                    <Slider  Maximum="360" Minimum="0" x:Name="slJoint2"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMin2" Padding="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Min</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbVal2" Padding="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Value</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMax2" Padding="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Max</TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint2, Path=Minimum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  x:Name="TbMinBox2" Padding="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slJoint2, Path=Value,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbValBox2" Padding="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint2, Path=Maximum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbMaxBox2" Padding="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"></TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Padding="3"> Joint 3</TextBlock>
                    <Slider Maximum="360" Minimum="0" x:Name="slJoint3"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMin3" Padding="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Min</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbVal3" Padding="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Value</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMax3" Padding="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Max</TextBlock>

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint3, Path=Minimum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  x:Name="TbMinBox3" Padding="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slJoint3, Path=Value,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbValBox3" Padding="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint3, Path=Maximum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbMaxBox3" Padding="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"></TextBox>

                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Padding="3"> Joint 4</TextBlock>
                    <Slider Maximum="360" Minimum="0" x:Name="slJoint4"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMin4" Padding="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Min</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbVal4" Padding="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Value</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMax4" Padding="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Max</TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint4, Path=Minimum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  x:Name="TbMinBox4" Padding="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slJoint4, Path=Value,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbValBox4" Padding="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint4, Path=Maximum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbMaxBox4" Padding="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"></TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Padding="3"> Joint 5</TextBlock>
                    <Slider Maximum="360" Minimum="0" x:Name="slJoint5"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMin5" Padding="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Min</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbVal5" Padding="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Value</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMax5" Padding="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Max</TextBlock>

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint5, Path=Minimum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  x:Name="TbMinBox5" Padding="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slJoint5, Path=Value,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbValBox5" Padding="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint5, Path=Maximum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbMaxBox5" Padding="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"></TextBox>

                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Padding="3"> Joint 6</TextBlock>
                    <Slider Maximum="360" Minimum="0" x:Name="slJoint6"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMin6" Padding="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Min</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbVal6" Padding="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Value</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMax6" Padding="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Max</TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint6, Path=Minimum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  x:Name="TbMinBox6" Padding="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slJoint6, Path=Value,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbValBox6" Padding="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="50" Width="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slJoint6, Path=Maximum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbMaxBox6" Padding="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"></TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Padding="3"> Tool Tip</TextBlock>
                    <Slider Maximum="360" Minimum="0" x:Name ="slToolTip"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMin7" Padding="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Min</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbVal7" Padding="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Value</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TbMax7" Padding="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Max</TextBlock>

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slToolTip, Path=Minimum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  x:Name="TbMinBox7" Padding="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slToolTip, Path=Value,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbValBox7" Padding="0" Grid.Column="1" MaxWidth="50" Margin="82,0,87,0"/>
                        <TextBox Text ="{Binding ElementName=slToolTip, Path=Maximum,StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TbMaxBox7" Padding="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" MaxWidth="50"></TextBox>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="BtnAddWaypoint" Padding="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="213">Add Waypoint</Button>
                        <Button x:Name ="BtnClear" Padding="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="203">Clear Last</Button>
                        <Button x:Name="BtnClearAll" Padding="3" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="213">Clear All</Button>

                    </Grid>
                    <TextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollBar.Scroll="TextBox_Scroll" Padding ="3" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" Margin="0,0,5,0" Height="50"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
            <GroupBox Height="718">
                <TabControl>
                    <TabItem Header="Simulation">

                        <Grid Name="overall_grid" Height="669">

                            <!-- Helper to control the small box in order to find points in the 3D world, made invisible -->


                            <!-- The HelixViewport3D supports camera manipulation, and can be used just like the Viewport3D -->
                            <HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" Margin="0,124,0,0" Name="m_helix_viewport" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="475">

                                <!-- Remember to add light to the scene -->
                                <HelixToolkit:SunLight/>

                                <!-- The content of this visual is defined in MainViewModel.cs -->
                                <ModelVisual3D Content="{Binding our_Model}"/>

                            </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D>
                        </Grid>










                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="Setup">

                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="Settings">

                    </TabItem>

                </TabControl>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Update -

Checking for the value changed event and then posting code in the created event handler to rotate the model seems to have worked. However, 0-360 seems to rotate my model more than one revolution

```
 private void slJoint1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            Matrix3D transformationMatrix7 = Shoulder1.Transform.Value; //Gets the matrix indicating the current transformation value
            transformationMatrix7.Rotate(new Quaternion(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), slJoint1.Value)); ; //Makes a rotation transformation over this matrix
            Shoulder1.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(transformationMatrix7);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Events i passed my angles from the GUI to the Code behind and then used the following code below to update the rotation angle of my models.

```
   public void Move_Joint1(double angle1,double angle2)
        {

            Transform3DGroup Joint1Group = new Transform3DGroup();


            Joint1Group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 185)));
            Joint1Group.Children.Add(new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), angle1)));

            Shoulder1.Transform = Joint1Group;

            Move_Joint2(angle1,angle2);

        }


 public void Move_Joint2(double angle1,double angle2)
        {
            Transform3DGroup Joint2Group = new Transform3DGroup();

            Joint2Group.Children.Add(new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), -90)));

            Joint2Group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform3D(new Vector3D(150, 0, 253)));

            RotateTransform3D Joint2Rotation1 = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), angle1));
            Joint2Rotation1.CenterX = Joint2Group.Transform(new Point3D(0, -150, 0)).X;
            Joint2Rotation1.CenterY = Joint2Group.Transform(new Point3D(0, -150, 0)).Y;
            Joint2Rotation1.CenterZ = Joint2Group.Transform(new Point3D(0, -150, 0)).Z;
            Joint2Group.Children.Add(Joint2Rotation1);

            Point3D origin = Joint2Group.Transform(new Point3D(0, 0, -70));
            RotateTransform3D Joint2Rotation = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0.1, 0, 0), angle2));
            Joint2Rotation.CenterX = origin.X;
            Joint2Rotation.CenterY = origin.Y;
            Joint2Rotation.CenterZ = origin.Z;

            Joint2Group.Children.Add(Joint2Rotation);

            Arm1.Transform = Joint2Group;

        }
```